# cpp include .cpp files in main source file causes "duplicate symbol" error

Tags: c++, header-files, software-design

I am stuck at how to separate a project into few source files and header files. My current practice seems to be clumsy and mistaken. Any comment is appreciated!

I have four files:

- `main.cpp` is the main program. It will create a few tree nodes, and call a function to traverse them.
- `TreeNode.h` is the header file where I declare a simple class `TreeNode`
- `TreeNode.cpp` is where I define a constructor of the class `TreeNode`
- `utils.cpp` is where I define a few functions on `TreeNode`, like printing out the tree.

The question is, where should I `include` the `TreeNode.h` file?

- If I include it both in `main.cpp` and `utils.cpp` (since they both use the `TreeNode` class, my compiler gives me a "duplicate symbol" error. This might be because I included `utils.cpp` in `main.cpp` as well.

Like this :

```
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/utils.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable main
duplicate symbol __Z13inorder_printP8TreeNode in:
    CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/main.dir/utils.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __Z16inorderTraversalP8TreeNode in:
    CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/main.dir/utils.cpp.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [main] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [main] Error 2`
```

- If I only include `TreeNode.h` in `main.cpp` file, the `utils.cpp` file will not compile. It gives an error `error: unknown type name 'TreeNode'`

**Edit:**

Here are the four files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "TreeNode.h"
#include "utils.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    TreeNode * root = new TreeNode(0);
    root->right = new TreeNode(2);
    root->right->right = new TreeNode(3);

    // inorder_print(root);
    std::vector<int> v = inorderTraversal(root);

    // print out vector
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i){
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

TreeNode.h

```
#ifndef TREE_TREE_H
#define TREE_TREE_H

class TreeNode{
public:
    int val;
    TreeNode * left;
    TreeNode * right;

    TreeNode(int x);
};

#endif //TREE_TREE_H
```

TreeNode.cpp

```
#include "TreeNode.h"

TreeNode::TreeNode(int x) {
    val = x;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
}
```

utils.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// #include "TreeNode.h"

// tested correct
void inorder_print(TreeNode * root){
    // print out the tree content in inorder traversal
    while(root != nullptr){
        std::cout << root->val << std::endl;
        inorder_print(root->left);
        inorder_print(root->right);
        break;
    }
}

std::vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode * root){
    std::vector<int> v;
    while(root != NULL){
        v.push_back(root->val);
        if (root->left != NULL){
            v.insert(v.end(), inorderTraversal(root->left).begin(), inorderTraversal(root->left).end());
            break;
        }
        if (root->right != NULL){
            v.insert(v.end(), inorderTraversal(root->right).begin(), inorderTraversal(root->right).end());
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Have you used header guards?  You don't include cpp files in another.  You create another header file for it.

Comment: @MichaelSurette No, I've not heard of it before. but thanks for introducing me to it!

Comment: You should include the `TreeNode.h` file in any source file that needs it. You should also include it in this question, since it's the core of the problem you're having.

Comment: Can you provide at least the include section of every file?

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for offering to inspect. Posted now.

Comment: @rcosteira posted now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't `#include "utils.cpp"` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as your compiler output shows, you're compiling both `main.cpp` and `utils.cpp`. Your `main.cpp` includes `utils.cpp` so functions you defined there are compiled twice hence duplicate symbols.

As the rule of thumb, never include .cpp files. Consider `#include` as literal inclusion of content of one file into another file. I suppose you tried to resolve the issue that you couldn't use stuff from `utils.cpp` in `mail.cpp`. To solve this add function *declarations* in `TreeNode.h` (like just a signature of a function, e.g. `int foo(double);` while keeping their *definition* in `utils.cpp` (e.g. `int foo(double) { return 0; }`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use include guards. For instance:

```
#ifndef TREENODE_H
#define TREENODE_H

class TreeNode 
{
    // stuff
};

#endif /* TREENODE_H */
```

Note that the guard name (in this case, `TREENODE_H`) has to be unique for each header file. And yes, it can be whatever you want.

**Edited after question edit:**

Don't include `utils.cpp`. In fact, never include a `*.cpp`:) change it to `#include "utils.h"`. This is what is causing that linker error.

Comment: While that's good advice, it doesn't address the **linker** error.